# sum for every row in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following array in my Model in mongoose.

```
 "university_subject_list: [{
                
            name:{type:String },
            level:{type:String },
             lecture_hours:{type:Number, default:0 },
            labs_hours:{type:Number, default:0 },
           
         
                     
        }]


Is it possible to have another field inside that array that calculates the sum of labs and lecture hours like below

 "university_subject_list": [
                {
                    "name": "Biology",
                     "level":"BA"
                      "lecture_hours":10
                        "labs_hours":5
                        "Tot":15
                "_id": "63638410c7482993a7349f92"
                },
                {
                        "name": "Literature 2",
                         "level":"BA"
                          "lecture_hours":10
                        "labs_hours":10
                        "Tot":20"
               
               }]
```

I tried with virtuals  but it gives me the total for all subjects and I want the total per subject

Comment: Nobody can help me on this?